# I want to insert texts into multiple textfields with a list

Tags: java, jcalendar

I'm trying to make a schedule. To bring the list of data from the server, I use this:

```
public List getListaCon(Date datacon, Date horacon, Date horacon1){
   em.getTransaction().begin();
   Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c from Consulta c where c.datasconsulta = :datacon and c.hora BETWEEN :horacon and :horacon1");
   query.setParameter("datacon", datacon);
   query.setParameter("horacon", horacon);
   query.setParameter("horacon1", horacon1);
   List<Consulta> lista = query.getResultList();
   em.getTransaction().commit();
   return lista;
 
}
```

[image: essa é a minha tabela do banco de dados]

I basically set a date and time through a `JCalendar` to create a new tuple on that table in the database. So far so good; the problem is to populate my textfields with the data coming from the server. This would be much easier with a `JTable` but it doesn't look good visually. I was wondering how I would do to fill these different `JTextField`s with a `List<Consulta>` that is fed with data from the database.
Here is a screenshot of an example of how the application works:

[image: schedule exemple]

Each line of `JTextField` that is separated by `JSeparator` would represent a scheduled time. For example, 07:00 would bring the name that was scheduled according to the time that was scheduled when saved, the second column would just be to add another field of that class.

Please if there is still any doubt about something, put it in the answers, so I can improve and facilitate understanding.

Comment: You will need to keep a list that references each jtextfield in order (or a hashmap with the time as the key). Then simply have your method split the data up into different times and use a loop to assign each event/task to the correct jtextfield using the list/hashmap.

Comment: I understood a little, but it wasn't clear enough in my head, could u exemplify it in a small piece of code? thanks.

Comment: I'd stick with a `TableModel` to hold events. Here's how I divided a `JTable` vertically. Here's more on [renderers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjtable%5d%20renderer).